# How to encrypt ViewState (server stored) that generates colon separated random numbers on client?

Tags: jsf, viewstate, mojarra

I have an application build on top of **Mojarra 2.1.20** (package com.sun.faces, RI for JSF 2.2 specification).
I have a context param javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD with value as server specified in my application deployment descriptor file web.xml

JSF is injecting the following ViewState hidden element on my post login page

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="random_number1:random_number2" autocomplete="off" />
```

The hidden element has value in some **random number** format and separated by a **colon**.
Since **STATE_SAVING_METHOD** is server, the actual ViewState in my case is getting stored on the **server**. But the client is just getting the **unique ViewState identifier or random numbers** from the server. My understanding is that when user submits a form with this hidden element, the server extracts these random numbers, identifies the actual ViewState from these numbers and then processes the request and sends back the response to the client/user.

Based on the above understandings, I have following queries on the ViewState and its vulnerabilities-

- Why two colon separated random numbers instead of one? What these two
  colon separated random numbers represents? What autocomplete="off" means?
- Does these server generated random number map to actual ViewState
  stored on the server? Is this understanding correct?
- Are these server generated random numbers already in encrypted
  format? Is encryption required on these random numbers to potentially
  avoid data leak and other vulnerabilities in the application?
- How to encrypt these random numbers in my case when ViewState is
  saved on server?
- Could we somehow avoid injection of the element in sources without
  getting displayed as hidden element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why two colon separated random numbers instead of one? What these two colon separated random numbers represents?*

The view state is basically stored in a nested map like as `Map<FirstId, Map<SecondId, ViewState>>`. This map is in turn stored in the `HttpSession`. The first ID is the 'logical' view ID (basically representing XHTML page itself) and the second ID is the 'actual' view state ID.

> *What autocomplete="off" means?*

It prevents web browsers from autofilling the value of the input element with previously submitted value from the browser cache. It should not be needed because the value is already prepopulated and the input element is a hidden type, but older Firefox versions were known to incorrectly overwrite this. Using `autocomplete="off"` is basically a [work around](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/1133) against them.

> *Does these server generated random number map to actual ViewState stored on the server? Is this understanding correct?*

Yes.

> *Are these server generated random numbers already in encrypted format? Is encryption required on these random numbers to potentially avoid data leak and other vulnerabilities in the application?*

No.

> *How to encrypt these random numbers in my case when ViewState is saved on server?*

Not needed.

> *Could we somehow avoid injection of the element in sources without getting displayed as hidden element?*

Not needed. You would in first place still need the `JSESSIONID` cookie in order to be able to successfully perform view state injection. But when one already has the `JSESSIONID` cookie at hands then you've anyway **much bigger** problems than only `ViewState` tampering, such as potentially a gaping XSS hole. Moreover, in case of server side state saving the "injected" view state can only be user's own view state obtained from another page in the same HTTP session and absolutely not a random one from a completely different user/session.

Your security concern would only apply if the view state was stored in the `ServletContext` (the application scope) instead of in the `HttpSession` (the session scope). But this is clearly not the case.

#### See also:

- [Reusing ViewState value in other session (CSRF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373089/reusing-viewstate-value-in-other-session-csrf/)
- [Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-jsf-saves-the-state-of-ui-components-on-server/)
- [com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession vs com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105439/com-sun-faces-numberofviewsinsession-vs-com-sun-faces-numberoflogicalviews)
- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf)

Comment: @BaluC What the inner map object's value ViewState represents in the nested Map<FirstId, Map<SecondId, ViewState>>? Also any reason why server requires the 'logical' view ID of the page? Does the framework passes the actual structure of the page without any data in nested Map object in VIewState?

Comment: The value represents the view state itself. The logical view id is used so it's much easier manageable on a per-logical-view-id basis. Your last question makes no sense. I guess you have no clear idea what exactly a "view state" is. In that case, head here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475564

Comment: Thanks for the link. Per the actual structure of the page in my last query, I meant with  the original JSF component tree. Could we say that the component tree structure makes up ViewState object on the client and forwarded to server along with firstId and secondId. Is this correct understanding? I am trying to understand the complete Life Cycle of JSF ViewState. Any pictorial rep of ViewState lifecycle would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Absolutely not the component tree. It's basically rebuilt from scratch during view build time and then any attributes modified in previous request are restored from the view state during postback. Drill down into the "See also" links and the "See also" links thereof, if any, to learn more and more. One of them is https://stackoverflow.com/q/31890433

Comment: ok got it, will go over the links. My vulnerability team has insisted for encryption of ViewState. But as you mentioned that Encryption is Not Needed, is there any reasons that these numbers should not be encrypted in order to better convince them?

Comment: As answered, it will require hijacking the session cookie in order to be able to change the view state. But when you already have the session cookie in first place then you have much bigger problems than merely a "injected" view state from another page of exactly the same user (impossibly of a different user).