# How to pass a value back and forth with every Request in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, csrf-protection

In order to reinforce **CSRF** protection in my **JSF 2.1(Mojarra)** app, I would like to send with every request/response (Every HTTP interaction with the server GETs and POSTs) a value  and validate it against an existing one on the server side that was created the moment a successful login was made.

I tried a nested `<input type="hidden">` in a `<p:fragment autoUpdate="true">` with a `@RequestScoped` bean but i can't afford to go to every `<p:commandButton>` in my templates and add the id of the form in the `update` attribute to perform the update(this will trigger validation in the `@PostConstruct` annotated method).

What are your suggestions ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant upgrade to 2.2.

Comment: Any one of JSF's back-end components (Phase listener, Navigation Handler, ViewHandler e.t.c.) can provide this

Comment: For the Response yes but not for the request..

Comment: Should be unnecessary for GETs: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/115810 . POSTs should already be protected by ViewState.

Comment: A phase listener is good across all phases of the JSF lifecycle. Even simpler: a basic servlet filter

Comment: A filter will allow me to add param/value to the Request but that's worthless , it doesn't make any sense altering the request on the server side.

Comment: What exactly is the real world security issue with your particular JSF application? Are you using client side state saving orso? If so, then this is possibly your answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/30507389. JSF has implicit CSRF protection already. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7722159. CSRF on GET is indeed nonsense unless you let your webapp manipulate sensitive data on GET instead of POST, which in turn is a bad practice and can better be solved by simply using POST instead of GET for such case. See also comments on currently accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26969415